# Displaying cart total in Rails, the Rails way

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, shopping-cart

I have to display the total price on a checkout page after the user has entered the shipment details. My Cart model has a total_price method which I use on the view to display the total price like

```
    <%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %>
```

Now I want to show the grand total which is total_price + shipment. Shipment is calculated using three parameters **weight**, **state** and **provider**. Assuming that **state** and **provider** are constant for now we just have to worry about the **weight**. So for this I have a shipment_rate method in the cart model which is something like.

```
    def shipment_rate(weight, provider, state) 
      # calculation code here
    end
```

Is it good to use this method in the view like this:

```
    <%- shipment = cart.shipment_rate(weight,'UPS','AK')%>
```

For this I have to provide the total weight of the cart items as well which I can calculate using the method @cart.total_weight. What is the Rails way of doing this? Is it good to call these methods from the View as follows:

```
    <%- total = @cart.total_price %>
    <%- weight = @cart.total_weight %>
    <%- shipment = cart.shipment_rate(weight,'UPS','AK')%>
    ...
```

and then use these values below in the same View like

```
    <span>Amount: <%= number_to_currency total %></span>
    <span>Shipment: <%= number_to_currency shipment %></span>
    <span>Total: <%= number_to_currency total + shipment %></span>
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity: why aren't you using [Spree Commerce](http://spreecommerce.com)?

Comment: @RyanBigg I was planning to use [active_shipping](https://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping) but the client has some custom implementation in mind

Comment: What kind of custom implementation? I'm interested in what they have in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd put it all back in the model like this:

```
<span>Amount: <%= number_to_currency @cart.subtotal %></span>
<span>Shipment: <%= number_to_currency @cart.shipping %></span>
<span>Total: <%= number_to_currency @cart.total %></span>
```

Where subtotal is what you're now calling "total_price" and "total" is subtotal+shipping

After all - a cart already knows its own weight and how to calculate shipment rate from that - so all you need to ask it for is the shipment rate.
You can pass values into it if you need to eg:

```
<span>Amount: <%= number_to_currency @cart.subtotal %></span>
<span>Shipment: <%= number_to_currency @cart.shipping(provider,state) %></span>
<span>Total: <%= number_to_currency @cart.total(provider,state) %></span>
```

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good, but I have one more question. Inside @cart.total method we will be calling **shipping** method again as that value is not stored somewhere.

Comment: Yes. If it's really not a very complex equation - it will have a near-insignificant impact on your response time, and the cognitive load saved by tucking it away out of sight in the model (plus ability to test it fully in your model tests) outweighs the minor impact of doubling up.
if it is a complex equation, then I suggest you google "memoization" - which just stores the value in a temporary variable on the actual *instance*, and thus won't re-run the logic. Just re-fetch the value. But honestly, unless it's a call that pings a remote server it's probably not worth it. :)

Comment: That's a "yes and no" answer. In theory, anything is a target to go into session. In practice - it's probably not worth the bother. If you find that the shipping-calculation is super heavy (talking seconds worth of wait here) and the shipping-values don't change much (which they will every time somebody adds something to their cart) then go for it... but I'd say it's over-engineering. Do if it becomes a problem for you - not until... :)